# laravel collection nested query

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-6

I'm new with laravel collection . i just want to make this query with collection

```
DB::select(SELECT id, user_id, created_at,latitude,longitude

FROM coordinates

WHERE created_at IN (

    SELECT MAX(created_at)

    FROM coordinates

    GROUP BY user_id));
```

according to the document https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections

this what i did and it gives me all the data
`$this->data['information'] = collect($response->json()['items']);`

***Edit:***

simply i need to produce that query (that i mentioned above) by using Collection.

This is the contents of $response->json()['items']

```
"#items: array:17 [▼ 0 => array:9 [▼ "id" => 977777779 "platform_id" => "msaeed" "platform_type" => 1 "status" => 1 "longitude" => 1.1 "latitude" => 1.1 "created_by" => "NMF" "created_at" => "2019-10-27T21:00:00Z" "updated_at" => "2019-10-28T07:58:36Z""
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you add more explanation?

Comment: @nmfzone sure, if you open the link of the document that i post , you will find methods that is used with collection class such as (where ,whereIn, etc), so by using those methods i want you to make the query that i mentioned above. hope it is clear now.

Comment: Oh okeee I see. I don't get it before. So you need to produce the same query using Collection, right? Let me try it.

Comment: Can you show us what is the `$response->json()['items']` contents?

Comment: @nmfzone yes , that's exactly what i want , i need to produce the same query using Collection .

Comment: $response = Zttp::withHeaders([
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ])->get(config('path') . '/api/v2/cord');

Comment: 'path' is my URL

Comment: I need the contents of `$response->json()['items']`, not the `$response` code..

Comment: @nmfzone do you mean this "#items: array:17 [▼
    0 => array:9 [▼
      "id" => 977777779
      "platform_id" => "msaeed"
      "platform_type" => 1
      "status" => 1
      "longitude" => 1.1
      "latitude" => 1.1
      "created_by" => "NMF"
      "created_at" => "2019-10-27T21:00:00Z"
      "updated_at" => "2019-10-28T07:58:36Z""

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can edit your question, then place it there.

Comment: @nmfzone ok .Thank you i will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query.

```php
$data = collect($response->json()['items']);

$data = $data->whereIn('created_at', $data->sortByDesc('created_at')
                                          ->groupBy('user_id')
                                          ->pluck('0.created_at'))
        ->onlyKeys(['id', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'latitude', 'longitude']);
```

The equivalent for the subquery:

```sql
SELECT MAX(created_at)
FROM coordinates
GROUP BY user_id
```

is

```php
$data->sortByDesc('created_at') // we use sortByDesc to produce the same result as `MAX`.
     ->groupBy('user_id')
     ->pluck('0.created_at') // then to get the max value, just get the first array after grouping.
```

To achieve the `select` statement, we need to create a little macro, i've named it `onlyKeys`:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Collection::macro('onlyKeys', function ($keys) {
    return $this->map(function ($value) use ($keys) {
        $tmpValue = (array) $value;

        if (is_array($tmpValue)) {
            $value = Arr::only($tmpValue, $keys);
        }

        return $value;
    });
});
```

You can register the macro in your **AppServiceProvider.php**.

**PS.** Why you need to querying using Collection? Is that data not come from DB?

Comment: Thank you, This is the answer i was looking for. i don't know how i could do it without your help.

Comment: the data is not coming from my local DB

Answer (score 0):

You want to collect array recursive
Unfortunately laravel does not have this feature:

you can write it on your own.
if you have helpers file you can write this method:

```php
function recursive_collect($array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = recursive_collect($value);
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return collect($array);
}
```

Or You can implement macro in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('recursive', function () {
    return $this->map(function ($value) {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            return collect($value)->recursive();
        }

        return $value;
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you